# how to get only left table from join sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I try to implement this query

```sql
SELECT [pelanggan].[id],
       [pelanggan].[nama_pelanggan],
       [pelanggan].[hp],
       Format(ABS(SUM([hutangs].[nominal])), N'c', N'id-ID') AS [total],
       [hutangs].[id_pelanggan] AS [hutangs.id_pelanggan]
FROM [pelanggan] AS [pelanggan]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [hutang] AS [hutangs] ON [pelanggan].[id] = [hutangs].[id_pelanggan]
WHERE [pelanggan].[kode_reseller] = N'MP0000001'
GROUP BY [pelanggan].[id],
         [pelanggan].[nama_pelanggan],
         [pelanggan].[hp],
         [hutangs].[id_pelanggan]
ORDER BY [pelanggan].[id]
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY;
```

to sequelize, i tried this code

```js
    Pelanggan.findAndCountAll({
      attributes: [
        'pelanggan.id',
        'nama_pelanggan',
        'hp',
        [db.sequelize.fn('Format', db.sequelize.fn('ABS',db.sequelize.fn('SUM', db.sequelize.col('hutangs.nominal'))) ,'c','id-ID') , 'total'],
      ],  
      include: [
        {
          model : db.hutang,
          required: false,
          attributes: [
            'id_pelanggan',
          ],
        }
      ],
      where: {
        kode_reseller: "MP0000001"
      },
      group: ['pelanggan.id','pelanggan.nama_pelanggan','pelanggan.hp','hutangs.id_pelanggan'],
      subQuery : false,
      limit: 5,
      offset: 0,
    })
    .then(data => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving tutorials."
      });
    });
```

but I'm getting error, when i console the query from sequelize i got this

```sql
SELECT [pelanggan].[id],
       [pelanggan].[nama_pelanggan],
       [pelanggan].[hp],
       Format(ABS(SUM([hutangs].[nominal])), N'c', N'id-ID') AS [total],
       [hutangs].[id] AS [hutangs.id],
       [hutangs].[id_pelanggan] AS [hutangs.id_pelanggan]
FROM [pelanggan] AS [pelanggan]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [hutang] AS [hutangs] ON [pelanggan].[id] = [hutangs].[id_pelanggan]
WHERE [pelanggan].[kode_reseller] = N'MP0000001'
GROUP BY [pelanggan].[id],
         [pelanggan].[nama_pelanggan],
         [pelanggan].[hp],
         [hutangs].[id_pelanggan]
ORDER BY [pelanggan].[id]
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY;
```

on the query from sequelize had **[hutangs].[id] AS [hutangs.id]** but i dont set hutangs.id on attribute sequelize how can I remove that ?

sorry for my bad English

Comment: i dont set it on attribute, it set automaticly and i want to remove it , how can i remove it

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: my query wont work cause **[hutangs].[id] AS [hutangs.id]** automaticly added to my query

Comment: What _error message_ do you observe? Please be more specific than "won't work".

Comment: **Column 'hutang.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.** this the error on query